# New post email alert

Tags: subscription, notifications

I'd like to display a checkbox with the option to subscribe to the site by email

I have seen a wordpress blog with the following label next to the said checkbox

Subscribe by email to this site

The problem is that i cannot see to find the plugin that displays it: i've tried Subscribe2 and Post Notification and Gurken for comment subscriptions.

Would you perhaps know what plugin i need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are often issues with setting up email subscriptions. Hosting providers are very tired of spam and often put harsh restrictions on email rate and volume, especially for cheaper hosting plans.

In practice such feature is often implemented with help of external service. FeedBurner is popular for this, because a lot of people use it for feeds anyway and it provides decent email subscription option.

See [FeedBurner Email Overview and FAQ](http://www.google.com/support/feedburner/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78982)

Comment: Been using Feedburner for a while and I'm very happy with it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at WP Responder:

http://www.wpresponder.com

It supports providing email subscription to all blog posts as well as particular blog categories.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Notifly with some success

Comment: Thanks but that's not the one i mean as it doesn't display any checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Rarst makes a good point about using an external service to avoid issues with hosting provider restrictions.

However, if you have a less restrictive host (and you can check with tech support to see what the limits are for your account), the [Subscribe2 plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) should do what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry but AFAIKT the Subscribe2 plugin doesn't do it. I've been playing around with it a few hours.